# gfortran Error: Nonnegative width required in format string at (1)

Tags: fortran, port, gfortran, g77

The code in question is this:

```
  subroutine PG_TLab_Write(c30,r,d)
  implicit none
  character*30 c30,leftjust
  real*4 r
  integer*4 d,k
  if (d.eq.0) then
    write(c30,'(i30)') nint(r)
  elseif (d.gt.0) then
    write(c30,'(f30.<d>)') r
  else
    k = abs(d)
    write(c30,'(1pe30.<k>') r
  endif
  c30 = leftjust(c30)
  if (d.lt.0) then
    k = index(c30,'E')
    c30 = c30(1:k-1)//'x10\\u'//c30(k+1:24)
  endif
  return
  end
```

It's really old (bad) code, and I'm not a fortran programmer.
The error it gives is the following:

```
Error: Nonnegative width required in format string at (1) pg-util.f:561.26:
```

It gives errors on the last 2 write statements in the segment.

My question is how do I make d and k unsigned integers so it will compile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't make d and k unsigned since Fortran does not have unsigned integers.

My guess, assuming that line 561 in the error message refers to the next-to-last line in the snippet you posted, is that the problem is in the variable format expression (the <k> thing). Variable format expressions is an extension to the standard which is not supported by gfortran. See the [section about variable format expressions in the gfortran manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Variable-FORMAT-expressions.html) for an example how to do the equivalent thing in a standard conforming way.

Comment: I removed the <k> line and hardcoded <d> to 30. That let it compile. We'll see if there are any adverse affects from doing that.